# Python Telegram Bot Send message with action

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using python telegram bot library in python 3 and I wrote this code:

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=update.message.chat_id , 
action = telegram.ChatAction.TYPING)
bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hi")
```

This code will send a Message to client properly, but I want when bot send a message to client, above of client screen (in telegram messenger)show that but is `Typing...`.
I use `action = telegram.ChatAction.TYPING` as an option in sendMessage method,
but it doesn't work and I can't find my problem.
any guide?

Comment: what is a statute??

Comment: The "Typing ...."  text will be shown when you are typing some text in telegram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is library ,  write `import telegram` instead `from telegram import *` .

Answer (score 1):

To ensure `ChatAction` is visible by user, you need to let several seconds of time delay after calling the `ChatAction` method:

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
from time import sleep
from random import random

bot.sendChatAction(chat_id=update.message.chat_id , 
action = telegram.ChatAction.TYPING)

sleep(random() * 2 + 3.)

bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hi")
```